# Increase Angular6 Library version automatically in DevOps

Tags: angular, devops, angular-library, build-pipeline

I am building an Angular Library to be used in other Angular Applications. I want to create a build pipeline in DevOps (VSTS) so after each commit to git, the library will be built and published as Artefacts to be used.

Till now everything works fine, my problem is with Angular Library version. If I tried to publish the Library with the same version, I receive this error:

> Forbidden The feed already contains the package 'my-lib' at version
>   '0.0.1': my-lib

My build pipeline:

[image]

To solve this problem, I have either to change the Version in the package.json before every builds [image]

Or through the cli: npm version 0.0.2

Can I do it automatically? which means, no need for extra actions except commit/push? I had searched for a long time, but couldn't find a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update your version you need to run `npm version` command by passing one of the following: `patch, minor` or `major` ->

- `npm version patch` would update your package version from `1.3.0` to
  `1.3.1`
- `npm version minor` would update your package version from
  `1.3.0` to `1.4.0`
- `npm version major` would update your package
  version from `1.3.0` to `2.3.0`

You can add this command to your pipeline to be run when you merge to `master` or however you pipeline is set up.

Please see: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version